# Using python to find objects in array with same starting characters

Tags: python

I'm new to python and would like to know if there is an easy way to search for Strings in array that have the same starting characters.

for example I have a list

```
ex = [exA, exB, teA, exC]
```

and want to get result for everything matching the first two characters
something like this:
 {'ex' : 3, 'te' : 1}

I have tried working with the Counter method from collections but I cant get a result as shown above.

thank you in advanced

Comment: modify the original `list` first like so: `[x[:2] for x in ex]`. Then pass it to `Counter`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you slice off the first two characters of each element you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this

```
>>> import collections
>>> ex = ['exA', 'exB', 'teA', 'exC']
>>> collections.Counter(i[:2] for i in ex)
Counter({'ex': 3, 'te': 1})
```